# How do i change the default sound card?

Tags: sound, soundcard

I have an USB card, but the default card must be the onboard audio, i can change the default card in pulseaudio card, but i can't hear anything in Half Life 2, because the usb card is not the primary card.

```
$ aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 2: Headset [HP Digital Stereo Headset], dispositivo 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 3: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 13.10 go to: System Stteings->Sound
The list on the left shows all working sound devices. Select the sound device you would like it to use, and it should direct all audio output to that device. I had to do this for my USB headset, but now once I plug it in, it automatically defaults to it.

Comment: No. I have done this when i have installed ubuntu. But this is another trouble, because the game use the default card of alsa or something not pulseaudio

Comment: Check this out. http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=114968

Comment: logconns comment talks about changing the order of preferred sound card for usb.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved your problem, but for the sake of completeness the following description helped me change the order of the usb devices:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices#Information_as_of_2014.2C_March_20

Essentially you can change the card index in */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* eg. like this

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
```

Comment: How? Can you put the essential parts of the link in your answer and just leave that as a reference? If that link ever goes dead, it's a problem.